# Is it good practice to replace water in Lucky Bamboo everyday?

Tags: lucky-bamboo

My sis replaces water in the jar everyday, the plant grew well but it started turning yellow after couple of weeks. The plant was in bright indirect light.

I thought the plant needed less water changing, maybe I am wrong. I can't say why the plant grew well for few weeks and then started turning yellow. What's the reason for that? Is changing the water everyday the culprit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past year I've only changed the water once for mine and they seem to be doing fine.

I suspect the yellow leaves could be caused by the constant onslaught of chlorinated water.

I'd suggest changing the water less frequently.  (Maybe every two weeks would make her happy.) More importantly, I'd recommend using declorinated water. One easy way to get that is to let tap water sit out for 24h first to let the chlorine evaporate. (If your water also has chlorimide that won't evaporate. I'm not sure if you'd need to worry about that, but filtering your tap water should also take care of that.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43564/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-is-it-good-practice-to-replace-water-in-lucky-bambo).